# 'System.Threading.Tasks.Task' does not contain a definition for 'Result'

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-4.0

I have a facebook query which is as follows

```
var client = new FacebookClient(accessToken);
var dynamic = client.Get(connection, new { fields = "name,from,story,message,picture,comments", limit = count});
foreach (var dynPost in results.data)
{
     posts.Add(ConvertToPost(dynPost));
}
```

I am trying to make this quicker by making lots of smaller requests to Facebook in parallel.

```
using (profilingService.Start("Facebook calls"))
{ 
    var pullSize = 25;
    var numberOfCalls = (int)Math.Ceiling(count / (double)pullSize);

    var taskQueue = new Queue<Task>();
    for (int i = 0; i < numberOfCalls; i++)
    {
        taskQueue.Enqueue(Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
        {
            var offset = i * pullSize;
            var client = new FacebookClient(accessToken);
            return client.Get(connection, new { fields = "name,from,story,message,picture,comments", limit = 25, offset = offset });
        }));
    }

    Task.Factory.ContinueWhenAll(
        taskQueue,
        tasks =>
        {
            //t.Result here is giving me the error
            var results = tasks.Select(t => t.Result);
            foreach (var result in results)
            {
                foreach (var dynPost in result.data)
                {
                    posts.Add(ConvertToPost(dynPost.data));
                }
            }
        });
}
```

First of all I am getting an error on `var results = tasks.Select(t => t.Result);`

> Error 361 'System.Threading.Tasks.Task' does not contain a definition
>   for 'Result' and no extension method 'Result' accepting a first
>   argument of type 'System.Threading.Tasks.Task' could be found (are you
>   missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

t is of type `Task<AntecedentResult>`

Which led me to this page, but have still not able to resolve it. [What's wrong with this async Task method?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9799771/whats-wrong-with-this-async-task-method)

Also, I haven't had much experience with this sort of parallel coding, anything I am doing wrong or should be doing in a different way?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is the `Queue<Task>`. `Task` alone does not have a `Result` property. However, `Task<Foo>` has a `Result` property of type `Foo`. (I don't know what `client.Get(...)` returns, let's call it `Foo` for now:

```
var taskQueue = new Queue<Task<Foo>>();
```

The `ContinueWhenAll` method does not support `Queue<>`, only `Task[]` and `Task<>[]`, so you need to convert it to an array first.

```
Task.Factory.ContinueWhenAll(
    taskQueue.ToArray(),
    tasks =>
    {
        var results = tasks.Select(t => t.Result);
        foreach (var result in results)
        {
            ...
        }
    });
}
```