# How to get the data with a rest api?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I'm very new to .Net and I'm trying to retrieve the data after a call to a rest method

My function is actually like this:

```
    private Task<HttpResponse> getUser(string user)
    {
        string url = "http://ws.audioscrobbler.com/2.0/?method=user.getinfo&user=" + user + "&api_key=xxx&format=json";
        var client = new HttpClient();

        return client.GetAsync(url).ContinueWith(request =>
            {
                var response = request.Result;
                response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
                return response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().ContinueWith(t =>
                    {
                        var result = new HttpResponseMessage();
                        response.CreateContent(t.Result);
                        return response;
                    });
            }).Unwrap();
    }
```

But I get this error :

> 'System.Net.Http.HttpResponseMessage' does not contain a definition
>   for 'CreateContent' and no extension method 'CreateContent' accepting
>   a first argument of type 'System.Net.Http.HttpResponseMessage' could
>   be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Maybe I just forgot something, but even after some search I didn't find any solution.
Are there any alternative ways to solve?

Thanks for the help

Comment: If you're using async, you should use `await` keyword so that it reads more like synchronous code and is easier to understand. Your lambdas make it hard to understand the flow of your code. Also, there is no `CreateContent()` method on [HttpResponseMessage](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.http.httpresponsemessage(v=vs.118).aspx). Perhaps you wanted to just set the Content property?

Comment: There's a good example of doing what you're trying to do here [C# HttpClient](http://www.dotnetperls.com/httpclient) and here [Don't Block on Async Code](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/07/dont-block-on-async-code.html).  As mason said, use await instead of lambdas.

Comment: see this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/9800077/2374987

Comment: @feras Salim : This post is the one I was looking to when I made my code

Comment: which .Net version you work on??

Comment: @FerasSalim I'm currently on .Net 4.5

Comment: which version? .Net 3, .Net 4, .Net 4.5????????

Comment: .Net 4.5 (Sorry my Num Lock key wasn't active and I didn't notice)

Comment: show your web.config file

Comment: The one on the root or the on on the views folder ?

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution.

Solution: Add a reference to **System.Net.Http.Formatting.dll.** This assembly is also available in the **C:\Program Files\Microsoft ASP.NET\ASP.NET MVC 4\Assemblies folder.**

The method ReadAsAsync is an extension method declared in the class HttpContentExtensions, which is in the namespace System.Net.Http in the library System.Net.Http.Formatting.

Reflector came to rescue!